# Check if row exists using Mysql store procedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

At mysql command prompt, I run:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE name1 like '%Nadiya%')
```

returns

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE name1 like '%Nadiya%')
1
```

but following procedure doesn't print as Exists. I need to get inside IF statement.
Please let me know what change could get me inside IF.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE verifyAndUpdate30(in searchName  varchar(12), in searchId   bigint, inout result int)
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE name1 like '%searchName%') ) THEN 
        SELECT 'EXISTS';
        UPDATE TEST SET testFlag=1 WHERE id=searchId;
        SET result=1;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'DOES NOT EXISTS';
    END IF; 

    SELECT result;
END 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Call to procedure:

```
SET @increment = 0;
call verifyAndUpdate30('Nadiya', 5532, @increment);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct the `LIKE` string the hard way, using `CONCAT('%', searchName, '%')`:

```
,,,
IF ( SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM test1
    WHERE name1 like CONCAT('%', searchName, '%')   -- Build %searchName% from parts
 ) ) THEN 
,,,
```

Comment: @VishalPatel try without the inner `SELECT`, like: `IF (EXISTS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...)) THEN`

Answer (score 4):

#### You need to concatenate.

Since `searchName` can be taken as hardcoded string, replace your query this way:

```
CONCAT('%', searchName, '%')
```

#### Full Code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE verifyAndUpdate30(in searchName  varchar(12), in searchId   bigint, inout result int)
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test1 WHERE name1 like CONCAT('%', searchName, '%')) ) THEN 
        SELECT 'EXISTS';
        UPDATE TEST SET testFlag=1 WHERE id=searchId;
        SET result=1;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'DOES NOT EXISTS';
    END IF; 

    SELECT result;
END 
//
DELIMITER ;
```

See more about [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in MySQL.